# When and How JavaScript garbage collector works

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, v8, spidermonkey

I did read few articles like [this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) and [this one](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/) I got the idea of how GC happens in JavaScript

I still don't understand things like

a) When does Garbage collector kicks in ( it gets called after some interval or some conditions have to met) ?

b) Who is responsible for Garbage collection ( it's part of JavaScript engine or browser/Node ) ?

c) runs on main thread or separate thread ?

d) which one of the following have higher peak memory usage ?

```
// first-case
// variables will be unreachable after each cycle

(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    let name = 'this is name' + i;
    let index = i;
  }
})()
```

```
// second-case
// creating variable once

(function() {
  let i, name, index;

  for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    name = 'this is name' + i;
    index = i;
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

V8 developer here. The short answer is: **it's complicated**. In particular, different JavaScript engines, and different versions of the same engine, will do things differently.

To address your specific questions:

> a) When does Garbage collector kicks in ( it gets called after some interval or some conditions have to met) ?

Depends. Probably both. Modern garbage collectors often are generational: they have a relatively small "young generation", which gets collected whenever it is full. Additionally they have a much larger "old generation", where they typically do their work in many small steps, so as to never interrupt execution for too long. One common way to trigger such a small step is when N bytes (or objects) have been allocated since the last step. Another way, especially in modern tabbed browsers, is to trigger GC activity when a tab is inactive or in the background. There may well be additional triggers beyond these two.

> b) Who is responsible for Garbage collection ( it's part of JavaScript engine or browser/Node ) ?

The garbage collector is part of the JavaScript engine. That said, it must have certain interactions with the respective embedder to deal with embedder-managed objects (e.g. DOM nodes) whose lifetime is tied to JavaScript objects in one way or another.

> c) runs on main thread or separate thread ?

Depends. In a modern implementation, typically both: some work happens in the background (in one or more threads), some steps are more efficient to do on the main thread.

> d) which one of the following have higher peak memory usage ?

These two snippets will (probably) have the same peak memory usage: neither of them ever lets objects allocated by more than one iteration be reachable at the same time.

---

Edit: if you want to read more about recent GC-related work that V8 has been doing, you can find a series of blog posts here: https://v8.dev/blog/tags/memory

Comment: d) which one of the following have higher peak memory usage ?

Wont the first code snippet have higher peak memory (though it will be collected later by the GC) ?

Comment: @manjuv No, there is no reason why either of the two snippets should have higher peak memory usage than the other.